# One function for clickable checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel

Hye there.

I would like to ask for any ideas from anyone here.

I have a lot of checkboxes in a worksheet which I link with a chart in the same worksheet. I would like to make a function which run the same code for each of the checkboxes ( I have 24 check boxes overall) when it is click. If you have any idea or suggestion, do tell me.

Here is the idea of mine for the flow of the code. I just have the same flow of code.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("REPORT").Activate
    ActiveSheets.ChartObjects("STOCK MOVEMENT GRAPH").Activate
On Error GoTo 0

If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete

    Else
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Sheets("REPORT").Range("B4:AB4")
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("REPORT").Activate
    Worksheets("REPORT").ChartObjects("STOCK MOVEMENT GRAPH").Activate
On Error GoTo 0

If CheckBox2.Value = False Then
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Delete

    Else
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Sheets("REPORT").Range("B5:AB5"), PlotBy:=xlRows
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: You're going to have a problem with that approach as you're hard-coding your series numbers: if you delete series #1 then what was #2 will then become #1....

Comment: thanks for reminding me about that.. i didn't realized it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull out the common code into a standalone Sub:

```
Sub UpdateChart(rowNum As Long, AddingIt As Boolean)
    Dim cht As Chart, s As Series, rng As Range, f, i
    Set cht = Sheets("REPORT").ChartObjects("STOCK MOVEMENT GRAPH").Chart

    'what's the data range?
    Set rng = Sheets("REPORT").Range("B3").Offset(rowNum, 0).Resize(1, 2)

    If AddingIt Then
        'note: not checking if already added....
        cht.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=rng
    Else
        For i = cht.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(i)
            f = s.Formula
            If InStr(f, rng.Address()) > 0 Then s.Delete
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Then your checkbox code reduces to this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    UpdateChart 1, CheckBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    UpdateChart 2, CheckBox2.Value
End Sub

'etc....
```